# Dynamic HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

I have a `HyperLink` along with other controls such as `Label` etc in a `GridView`.  The `Label`'s in the `GridView` are dynamically populated like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ClientName") %>'></asp:Label>
```

I am now trying to do something similar with HyperLink, as in:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='http://www.company.com?clientname=<%# Bind("ClientName") %>'>Client Name</asp:HyperLink>
```

This doesn't give me any errors, but the link becomes this:

```
http://www.company.com/?clientname=<%# Bind("ClientName") %>
```

instead of something like this:

```
http://www.company.com/?clientname=oshiro
```

Anyone know how to get the link to work properly instead of just outputing the asp.net code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ClientName", "http://www.company.com/?id={0}") %>'>Client Name</asp:HyperLink>
```